# Cepstrum In MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have tried and there is not proper function in MATLAB to calculate cepstrum.

By using commercial software and processing file `21.wav` it is possible to get this result:

[image: Cepstrum from commercial software]

How can I achieve the same results with MATLAB code? When I use the [`cceps`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cceps.html) or [`rceps`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/rceps.html) functions in MATLAB, the result is not even close:

```
%% Complex cepstral analysis
% Load Signal
A = importdata ('21.txt');
M = A(:,2);
Fs = 1552;
t = (0:length(M)-1)/Fs;
c = cceps(M);
plot(t,c)
xlabel('Time (s)')
title('Complex cepstrum')
ylim([0 0.2]);
xlim([0 4.6]);
```

The result is:

[image: Complex cepstrum]

```
%% Real cepstrum
% Load Signal
A = importdata ('21.txt');
M = A(:,2);
Fs = 1552;
t = (0:length(M)-1)/Fs;
c = rceps(M);
plot(t,c)
xlabel('Time (s)')
title('Real cepstrum')
ylim([0 0.2]);
xlim([0 4.6]);
```

The result is:

[image: Real cepstrum]

Comment: That last graph looks pretty similar. You could at least say which “commercial software” produced the first plot, and if they have a description of the math that they apply. They could be doing some extra steps, or they could be skipping some steps.

Comment: I wish I have more information but I do not, only figure and data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add x and y limit to your code and then compare the result

```
ylim([0 0.18]);
xlim([0 4.6]);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I just updated the question and also plots. It looks like it does not help.

Comment: in the commercial software, what is used? did you plot real or complex cepstrum? `rceps` will return real cepstrum and `cceps` will return complrx cepstrun. In the simulation and numerical analysis programs, there will be some minor differences, and the shape of the images will not be exactly the same, due to the difference of some parameters and algorithms such as Tolerance. But the result should be the same in other respects, such as prominent non-DC peak , for example

Comment: It is not know to me what commercial software uses and plots.